# when i select menu option once. onOptionsItemSelected is called twice. (Android)

Tags: android, menu

When my menu is clicked two times onoptionitemselected is called. how to stop it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.docmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.upload:
            Log.e("testing", "called");
            return true;
      case R.id.back:
        return true;
      default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
    }
```

my menu xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/upload"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_upload"
          android:title="@string/upload" />
    <item android:id="@+id/back"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_back"
          android:title="@string/back" />
</menu>
```

when upload icon is selected. In log testing called is printed two times.

Comment: how do you initialize the menu?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.Aboutus: 
        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(Welcome.this);
        d1.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);

        d1.show();



        break;
```

And make sure that you have created folder under res named menu. and make new menu.xml file

and put code like this in menu.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <item android:id="@+id/Aboutus"
     android:title="About Us" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about_us" />

<item android:id="@+id/Settings"
     android:title="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"/>



<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_help" />
```

Comment: now i added my xml and initializing menu code. what is the problem?

Comment: @Manoharan break each case properly.

Comment: how can u break if boolean should be returned

Answer (score 1):

onOptionsItemSelected return true is ok

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.my_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home Page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And create a new xml in menu folder and apply this code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/my_settings"
        android:title="@string/my_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```